# Can Zotero collections be used as hierarchical tags?

Tags: reference-managers

Few answers under [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/9594/410) have inspired me with the interesting idea of using Zotero "folders" (called collections) as hierarchical tags. Zotero does allow to create folder (=collection) tree in the left pane, and one reference can be put in more such collections. But, is Zotero able to search references present in two or more collections? That would be super cool, because then we could use those collections as tags!

Comment: Why not use tags as tags? (I realise they're not hierarchical, but nor are collections so far as I can see)

Comment: @SimonW collections are hierarchical in Zotero - you build the collection tree in left pane. I tend to prefer organizing using collections over tags in Zotero, because collections can be used for organizing the references in the GUI in much more easier and comfortable way.

Comment: Huh. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the tool is there))

[image]

Steps (look at the screenshot).

1. Open advanced search
2. Choose "Collection" as a search parameter
3. Choose collections to search in
4. Add more that one collection

That's it!